# Making username as link for visual force page

Tags: visualforce

How to make user name or user id as commandlink for visual force page or detail page of the record.?

Comment: please provide more details what you are trying to do and whatis not working.

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm?

Answer (score 2):

A more programmatic way to craft the link would be:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.User.View, User.Id)}">
    {!User.Name}
</apex:outputLink>
```

If you want to generate a `PageReference` programmatically, the correct approach is:

```
PageReference userView = new ApexPages.StandardController(userRecord).view();
```

If you want either of the above to work with `Salesforce1` or the `Service Console`, further consideration will be needed.

Comment: This is a better approach than hard coding the URL to /userId, since Lightning Experience doesn't use URLs in the same way as the old site, and $Action.User.View will probably be more robust over the long term.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

In VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!user.Name}" action="{!userDetail}">
    <apex:paramname="userId"value="{!user.Id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

In Apex Controller:

```
public PageReference userDetail() {
    String userId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('userId');
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+userId);
    return pageRef;
}
```

*Note:*

- I am passing userId as params assuming you are not using "User" StandardController in Apex page.
- I am not sure whether this is a hacky way since I have used **salesforce.com/ObjectId** to render detail of a given Salesforce object

**Solution 2:**

This is another simpler way I usually prefer. Create a Formula(Text) field on User Object, and use HYPERLINK method, if you are not so sticky about commandLink way

```
HYPERLINK(Id)
```